# vss 6.0.81.69 compatibility with vs 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

vss version 6.0.81.69 is not working with vs 2008? is there any solution to make them compatible.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated Visual Studio 2008 support for [Visual Sourcesafe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms181038%28v=vs.80%29) did not ship with VS2008 as it was supposed to. There is however a CTP with the VS2008/VSS integration you can download:

Link to the CTP download here:
[VS 2008 users: remember to download the SourceSafe CTP](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316025927/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richardb/archive/2007/11/19/vs-2008-users-remember-to-download-the-sourcesafe-ctp.aspx)

Blog related to VSS: [BUGBUG: poor title](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/richardb/)

> For Visual SourceSafe 6.0d to work on
> Visual Studio 2008, you’ll need to do
> a bit of manual labour at the command
> line.
>
> Make sure that Visual Studio is closed
> when you do this.
>
> Browse to your VSS6\win32 directory
> and run:
>
> “regsvr32 ssscc.dll”